# Hibernate vs Spring connection acquisition strategy

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

I'm trying to understand when exactly a database connection is aquired in an application that uses hibernate as an ORM & Spring for transaction management.

In [this](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-the-difference-between-hibernate-and-sprin-1) article, it says:

> If the transaction manager decides to create a new transaction, then it will:
>
> create a new entity manager
>
> bind the entity manager to the current thread
>
> grab a connection from the DB connection pool
>
> bind the connection to the current thread

However [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-aggressive-connection-release/) it says :

> Hibernate defers the database connection acquisition until the current transaction has to execute its first SQL statement (either triggered by a read or a write operation). This optimization allows Hibernate to reduce the physical transaction interval, therefore increasing the chance of getting a connection from the pool.

I can't understand how can Hibernate delay the connection aquisition if Spring decides to aquire it before.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't understand how can Hibernate delay the connection aquisition
> if Spring decides to aquire it before.

The decision is taken by the transaction manager and so potentially by the `JpaTransactionManager/HibernateTransactionManager`

Hibernate 5.2.0 introduces new property `hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit`

With this Hibernate can delay the database connection acquisition until there is a JDBC Statement to execute. otherwise the database connection is acquired when entering the `@Transactional` service method.

So to allow Spring wires this property into the JPATransactionManager during the setup of spring context you have to set this property in your application.properties/yaml -->

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit=true
```

Last thing required to do this --> setAutoCommit to false on the connection pool provider (by default HikariCP since Spring boot 2)

```
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
```